# Why was my question about WolframAlpha marked off topic

Tags: discussion

The original post can be found here: [Get WolframAlpha to treat all symbols as variables](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/281920/get-wolframalpha-to-treat-all-symbols-as-variables?noredirect=1#comment702948_281920)

There is a tag specifically for WolframAlpha called `wolfram-alpha-queries`. If this doesn't belong here, to what StackExchange do I submit WorlfamAlpha questions?

Comment: The [tag wiki](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha-queries) for that tag states: "Use this for questions about calling Wolfram Alpha from Mathematica. **Questions about Wolfram Alpha itself are off-topic.**"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what SE would cater to WolframAlpha questions - probably you would have the most luck with the regular StackOverflow site. Sorry we don't accept those queries here - it's been the subject of many discussions on the meta over the years.

Comment: So you mean to say if instead I called WolframAlpha from within Wolfram Language I could ask the question?

Comment: I would suggest that you would be willfully following the letter and not the spirit of the rule :) Even so, in that case, unless something has gone wrong with the actual querying (and not the query itself), it would most likely be marked off topic.
It's important to remember this is a community site with no Wolfram affiliation, specifically for Mathematica - we have essentially no insight into Wolfram Alpha beyond the fact that they are two products from the same company.

Comment: The issue is that these are TWO different languages. The Wolfram Mathematica language and the Wolfram alpha language are not the same, even though they have the name Wolfram in them.  So, this site is about the Wolfram Mathematica language only and about using Mathematica itself. It is like asking a Fortran question in a C forum, it will get closed.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, and first, a +1 to what @Nasser said. Having said that, I'm not really sure what you were expecting. WolframAlpha tries to handle queries, but what you posted was just some random-looking algebraic expression. It wasn't even an equation. And if you made it into an equation, it's still not obvious what you wanted to solve for. Now, I'm not proficient enough in WolframAlpha to give you a guaranteed suggestion to fix this, but I can suggest that at the very least you need to phrase your input as a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So you mean to say if instead I called WolframAlpha from within Wolfram Language I could ask the question?

Just like questions about Python are off-topic even though questions about calling Python from within Mathematica are on topic.  Ditto for Matlab.  Ditto for TeX. Ditto, ditto....

The on-topic questions are about how to transfer data/input/output between the systems and process it within Mathematica.  Sometimes the problems are hybrid, because the user has problems both with using Mathematica and with using the external app.  Those are usually okay, but ones in which the problem is centered in the external program are usually rejected.

The alternative in this case is https://community.wolfram.com. I do not think there is a better site for asking about W|A.